# Google Calendar entries from Meetup marked Private; family can't see I'm going out

Tags: google-calendar, meetup

I use Google Calendar and attend a few Meetups, and when I RSVP to a Meetup event, Gmail automatically makes an entry in my calendar for the Meetup from the notification email meetup sends. And keeps it updated, and that is *really* nice.

But... I've noticed that people I share my calendar with, like my wife, kids, and a few friends, can't see those events. They think I'm free that evening, when I'm not. That's (really) bad, because I depend on Google Calendar to keep us all on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix:

1. Open Google Calendar.
2. In the top right, click the Settings icon Settings > Settings.
3. Find the Events from Gmail section (stay in the "General" tab).
4. Change it to "calendar default" (assuming your default is public).
   You'll be asked whether to apply the new visibility setting to only
   new events, or both existing and new events.
5. At the bottom of the page, click Save.